cmake error: "include could not find requested file"
I want to build https://github.com/darlinghq/darling/ as described in the docs, but I get this error:
$ cmake ..

CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake:354 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /usr/lib/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMExports.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/external/metal/deps/indium/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake:375 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /usr/lib/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVM-Config.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/external/metal/deps/indium/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


Running this on a fresh install works fine, but it fails on my system.
The immediate problem is, that something goes wrong with computing the path. cmake looks at
/usr/lib/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMExports.cmake
but the file is here:
/usr/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMExports.cmake
Debuggin cmake shows this:
$ cmake --debug-output ..

CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake:354 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /usr/lib/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMExports.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/external/metal/deps/indium/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


   Called from: [2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake
                [1] /home/darling/src/external/metal/deps/indium/CMakeLists.txt
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake:375 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    /usr/lib/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVM-Config.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/external/metal/deps/indium/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


   Called from: [2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake
                [1] /home/darling/src/external/metal/deps/indium/CMakeLists.txt
   Returning to         /home/darling/src/external/metal
   Called from: [1] /home/darling/src/external/metal/CMakeLists.txt
   Returning to         /home/darling/src
   Called from: [1] /home/darling/src/CMakeLists.txt
   Returning to         /home/darling
   Called from: [1] /home/darling/CMakeLists.tx

I'm on Arch/Manjaro, but I ran this on a fresh Arch container and on a Manjaro Live CD and it worked fine for both. So the issues seems to be somehow realted to my system, maybe due to certain packages I have installed. Nevertheless I don't think this should happen, so I'm looking for some help with further debugging and maybe fixing this (either the build or my system).
-- Edit 1---
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake computes the path for LLVMExports.cmake:
# This file provides information and services to the final user.

# Compute the installation prefix from this LLVMConfig.cmake file location.
get_filename_component(LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX "${LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX "${LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX "${LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX}" PATH)

...

344: set(LLVM_CMAKE_DIR "${LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/llvm")
354:   include("${LLVM_CMAKE_DIR}/LLVMExports.cmake")


So there seems nothing be wrong with the file itself, but with the way these variables are computed for this build.

The path /usr/lib/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVMExports.cmake or its part is taken directly from the file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/LLVMConfig.cmake. Probably, you somehow corrupted content of that file.

My System = ?? Try to install dependencies for "your system" Share more information please. https://docs.darlinghq.org/build-instructions.html

@Tsyvarev file looks got, I updated that part

@JuanmaFeliu I'm on Arch and installed the dependencies as described!

The file looks good, but it assumes that both LLVMConfig.cmake and LLVMExports.cmake are in the same directory. However, you have the first file under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/llvm/ and the second file under /usr/lib/cmake/llvm. I don't know what is the correct location of those files when install llvm with the package manager. If running on a "fresh install" actually works, then you could check location of those files when it works, and compare with the location when it doesn't work.
